# How do i access this nested array so it will show my <input> field?

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder, formarray

I'm trying to show this input field of 'levels'.
Eventually I want to have an add button to create multiple levels.
Each learningGoal should get the levels before I create the learninggoals.
So the json should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "name rubric",
  "learningGoals": [
    {
      "description": "learning goal description",
      "levels": [
        {
          "name": "level name",
          "criteras": []
        }
        {
          "name": "level name",
          "criteras": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

At this moment the the 'levels' is null

```
<form [formGroup]="rubricForm">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>Naam & Niveaus</ng-template>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Naam" formControlName="name">
  </mat-form-field>

  <div formArrayName="learningGoals">
    <div *ngFor="let learningGoal of learningGoals().controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div formArrayName="levels">
        <div *ngFor="let level of levels?.controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Naam" formControlName="name">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

my typescript:

```
rubricForm: FormGroup
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.rubricForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ["", Validators.required],
    learningGoals: this.fb.array([
      this.initLearningGoal()
    ])
  });
}

initLevel() {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: "",
  });
}

initLearningGoal() {
  return this.fb.group({
    description: "",
    levels: this.fb.array([
      this.initLevel()
    ])
  });
}

rubric(): FormArray {
  return this.rubricForm.get("rubric") as FormArray;
}
learningGoals(): FormArray {
  return this.rubricForm.get("learningGoals") as FormArray;
}

get levels(): FormArray {
  return this.learningGoals()
    .get('levels') as FormArray;
}
```

I've tried removing the for loops but than it gives me the error:

ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'learningGoals -> levels'.

So I have to get the form group in between I guess.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this using the following method:

```
levels(i: number): FormArray {
    const learningGoal = this.learningGoals.at(i) as FormGroup;
    return learningGoal.get('levels') as FormArray;
  }
```

and using:

```
<div formArrayName="learningGoals">
    <div *ngFor="let learningGoal of learningGoals.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div formArrayName="levels">
        <div *ngFor="let level of levels(i).controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Naam" formControlName="name">
          </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteLevel(i, j)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="addLevel(i)">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```